# GMaps controls broken in GWT 1.6+?

Tags: gwt, google-maps

I've ported my GWT app to 1.7.0 from 1.5.2 and widgets that are used as a control on a GoogleMap no longer get ClickEvents. I've checked that the DOM insertion of the control is the same and there are no differences there. Since GWT 1.6 introduced a significant change in the way events are handled I'm thinking something has gone amis there.

I use a GWT image as a a GoogleMaps control:

```
  Image control = new Image("/oeg/images/info_32.png");
```

Which I place on the map using the Mapitz GMaps lib (yes I know its old, but I have kept supporting a working version that is updated - if anyone is interested just ask)

```
 GControlPosition infoPosition = 
      new GControlPosition(GControlAnchor.G_ANCHOR_TOP_RIGHT(),
                           new GSize(7, 30)); 
  getGmap().addControl(new GControl(control, infoPosition));
```

I've checked the compiled code and it literally just puts the html element on the map as a GControl just the way you'd expect and as I said I've checked the DOM to make sure nothing looks funny.

to get ClickEvents I used to do this...

```
  control.addClickListener(new ClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(Widget sender) 
        { 
            doTipOfTheDay(); 
        } 
    });
```

which I changed to this in the 1.6.0 world,

```
  control.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { 
        public void onClick(ClickEvent ce) 
        { 
            doTipOfTheDay(); 
        } 
    });
```

I've also tried explicitly sinking the click event with

```
   control.sinkEvents(Event.ONCLICK);
```

but none of this works in GWT-1.6.0/1.7.0 and it all worked fabulously in 1.5.2

Can anyone shed some light on this? Has anyone else run into event issues w/ controls on GMaps with GWT 1.6 and above?

FYI with other Gmaps objects I have no problems.  I'm getting mouse clicks on the map surface, on markers etc.

but controls, not so much

Comment: I've no direct answer. But these remarks might help:
 * Did you test it with both GWT 1.6(.4) and 1.7, because between both releases there are some differences. Specifically 1.7 supports IE8 and uses a different user.agent for IE8 for deferred binding.
 * You (probably) are aware there is an official google maps gwt api: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/ (just checking)?
 * Did this problem occur on different browsers?

Comment: thanks, I know about the gwt maps API, I'm kind of stuck short term with Mapitz because we have so much mapping code, given that, this isn't the issue as that specific code is transparent and is doing nothing that I would do if I hand coded a native method.

I haven't thought to try 1.6(x) that might shed some light on what in the GWT event management code is broken vis a vis GMaps